# New environment creates table at the top of document

Tags: floats, positioning, environments

I have the following code:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
   \centering
   \rowcolors{2}{smileOrange!25}{white}
   \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
       \theader{Importance & Titre du document & Auteur}

       \trow{1 & some-com-config-files.tar.gz & Florian Margaine}
       \trow{2 & some-com-solr-folder.tar.gz & Florian Margaine}
   \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Working fine. The table is correctly generated. (`\theader` and `\trow` are custom commands, `smileOrange` is a custom color.)

Wanting to get rid of the `\begin{table}` boilerplate, I created this new environment:

```
\newenvironment{smileTable}
{
   \begin{table}
   \centering
   \rowcolors{2}{smileOrange!25}{white}
}
{
   \end{table}
}
```

So I use this environment like this:

```
\begin{smileTable}
   \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
       \theader{Importance & Titre du document & Auteur}

       \trow{1 & some-com-config-files.tar.gz & Florian Margaine}
       \trow{2 & some-com-solr-folder.tar.gz & Florian Margaine}
   \end{tabular}
\end{smileTable}
```

(I keep the `\begin{tabular}` so that I can declare the number of columns. If you know of any better way, please say so. But this is not the point of this question.)

The issue is that the table generated with the new environment ends up at the top of the document, right after the table of contents. Why is that so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can give your environment an argument then use `\begin{tabular}{#1}` so that you pass in the tabular preamble as an argument to the environment.

The float placement is not affected by being in a local definition but by the fact that you have dropped the `[ht]` option.

Comment: That's it! Thanks. Do you have any more information about the `[ht]` option? [This PDF](http://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/latex/TableHelp1.pdf) only says that `t` stands for `top`, but I can't seem to find a complete documentation.

Comment: any latex tutorial should have information latex has (h)ere (t)op (b)ottom and (p)age float areas, by default in most calasses a float is tried in `[tbp]` so `[ht]` makes it try putting it "here"(ie not float anywhere) or at the top of a page, but disallws putting it on a float page (with only floats no body text) or at the bottom of a page. (Not including `p` is usually a bad idea that can make the float un-placeable)

Comment: Oh well, I guess I didn't read the right tutorials. Thanks!

Comment: @FlorianMargaine see section 2.12 of `texdoc lshort` (the not so short introduction to latex2e) for example.